# mySQL select close rows by date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, closest

i have stucked a bit, trying to solve my problem. I have similiar table in mySQL

--id------datetime------------------
|-1- |--- 2015-09-07 23:36:05--|
|-2- |---    2015-09-07 23:36:03--|
|-3- |---    2015-09-07 23:36:02--|
|-4-  |---   2015-09-07 23:36:06--|
|-5- |---    2015-09-07 23:36:01--|
|-7- |---    2015-09-07 23:36:04--|

I got parameter ID, for example 3 with limit 6, so i wrote where clause for the closest rows including the middle one like: 
(id > 3 - (limit / 2)) LIMIT 6

But now i get date and i need to select the closest rows (if limit is 6, so in result 3 rows < than $DATE and 3 rows > $DATE.

I wrote 2 queries which runs ok or union select, but i would like to find a solution to use just one more simple query, if somebody has a hint. Thanks much.

Comment: You want the 6 closest dates to the date with `id = 3`? Or actually the 3 closest bigger and the 3 closest smaller?

Comment: Better said, i need the closest rows for date ex. 2015-09-07 23:36:03 (#2) so the result should be #5 #3 #2 #7 #1 (LIMIT 4...)

Comment: I doubt there's anything better than union for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the closest rows, you can calculate the difference (for example, in seconds) between each row's date and the provided date.

Then get the ABS value and order by the difference.

Something like:

```
select id
from table
order by ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2015-09-07 23:36:03', the_date))
LIMIT 4
```

**EDIT**

If you want to order the results by date, you can treat the former query as a subquery, and reorder it:

```
select id, the_date
from (
select id, the_date
from the_dates
order by ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2015-09-07 23:36:02', the_date))
LIMIT 4
) a
order by a.the_date
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64517/9/0

Comment: But it returns only the closest after, not before, from example if choose '2015-09-07 23:36:02' (#3) it will return :03,:04.... I need also the closest ones before so result should be :01 - :02 :03 :04

Comment: @user2699185: did you try it? I am adding a SQLFiddle for you to see. I think it returns the right results...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64517/7/0

Comment: yeah, i did, i looked at the sqlfiddle, result contains the closest rows, it's good but any possibility to ORDER it BY date one more time ? Result is: :03, :02 :01 :04 -> :01 ... :02 ....

Comment: You can always reorder the results by putting them in a subquery, I edited my answer to add that possibility. New sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64517/9/0

Comment: Thanks much, dude. Works really well.